# How to change Focus when press enter react Class Component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is my first time coding react, I have Login Page Like this

```
class Login extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            username: null,
            password: null,
        }
        this.handleOnChangeUserName = this.handleOnChangeUserName.bind(this);
        this.handleOnChangePassword = this.handleOnChangePassword.bind(this);
    }
}
handleOnChangeUserName(event) {
    this.setState({ username: event.target.value });
}
handleOnChangePassword(event) {
    this.setState({ password: event.target.value });
}
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <TextField
                  value={this.state.username}
                  onChange={this.handleOnChangeUserName}
            />
            <TextField
                  value={this.state.password}
                  onChange={this.handleOnChangePassword}
            />
            <Button
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

how should I make change focus with enter, I want when user type in `TextField` and press enter focus goes to next `TextField`

Answer (score 0):

use **onKeyPress** props in textfelid inputs,

first asign state value for toggle

whenever the user hits the **enter** button then change the user to false like below

```html
state{
  user: true,
  password: true
}

 <input 
  type="text"
  onKeyPress = {(e)=>(e.key=='Enter'?this.setState({user:false, password:true}):" "
  className={this.state.user?"noshadowClass":"showShadowcssclass"}
  />

 <input 
  type="text"
  onKeyPress = {(e)=>(e.key=='Enter'?this.setState({user:true,password:true}):" "
  className={this.state.password?"noshadowClass":"showShadowcssclass"}
  />
```

refer this [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-euler-hhknn?file=/src/App.js)